# Does garbage collection in Java work inside the loop?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Suppose the following *code*:

```
public static void main(String []args) {
    MessageProcessor processor = Util.createMessageProcessor();
    MessageArchiver archiver = Util.createMessageArchiver();
    List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < Util.EXPECTED_TOTAL; i++) {

        Message msg = Util.random();
        processor.processMessage(msg);
        messages.add(msg);
        msg = null;
    }

    archiver.archiveMessages(messages, m -> m.getSubject().startsWith("A"));

    Util.validate();
}
```

I noticed that the method creates the object msg in each loop. To explicitly delete the object I set msg=null. My question is, will Java's auto garbage collection pick up the object at the end of **each** loop or after the **exit** of the loop.

Comment: "To explicitly delete the object I set msg=null" - that does not explicitly delete the object. Java provides no way to explicitly delete objects. msg=null only assigns that particular variable to null; it doesn't do anything to any objects.

Answer (score 7):

> My question is, will Java's auto garbage collection pick up the object at the end of each loop or after the exit of the loop.

Neither, it would only pick it up after `main` completes (when GC next runs, if it does*), because you're adding the message object to the `messages` list, which maintains a reference to the object, keeping the object from being eligible for GC. *Variables* aren't GC'd (in the sense you're referring to), *objects* are.

It's only at the end of `main` when `messages` goes out of scope that the list is eligible for GC, which means the list's entries are eligible for GC (provided nothing else is still referring to them).

Regarding the loop, there's no need for the `msg = null;` statement, it doesn't do anything significant. Your `msg` variable is scoped to the loop iteration and goes out of scope at the end of each loop iteration, which will release any hold it has on anything it's referring to.

---

**In general:** Worry about memory-related performance issues when you have a memory-related performance issue in front of you, not before. :-)

---

* "If it does" - On JVM termination, it could just deallocate the entire JVM heap without worrying about GC.

Comment: Deallocating the entire heap without doing garbage collection is the standard procedure for JVM exit. By the way, the invocation `Util.validate();` suggests, that there is hidden state stored in some `static` variables, so we can’t even say for sure that the `Message` instances become unreachable at method exit.

Comment: @Holger: Yeah, that's why I threw that postscript in there. And quite so, without knowing what `Util.random()` does (I don't see `Util.validate`?), we can't know for sure if `messages` is the only thing holding references (hence *"provided nothing else is still referring to them"*). :-)

Comment: `Util.validate();` is the last thing at the end of the method. It suggests that at this point of time there’s still something in the heap…

Comment: @Holger: Bizarre that my Ctrl+F didn't find it, I probably typed "until.validate" by mistake. (Not bizarre my eyes didn't, not this week. :-) )

Answer (score 2):

Garbage collection happens outside the scope of your application, it happens in the underlying runtime. It is triggered by your application making a request to the runtime to allocate a new object (normally with the `new` keyword, but in your case `Util.random()` will be creating the new objects).

In it's simplest form, if the runtime can not find enough space on the heap to place this new object then it will start a garbage collection cycle. At this point it will freeze the running of your application and then remove all the no longer referenced objects hopefully leaving enough space to allocate the new one. At which point your application will resume.

Slightly smarter GC algorithms make you pay a tax every time you allocate an object. The tax still pauses the application, but only for the time it takes to check and remove unreferenced objects from a small section of the heap. This leads to much short periods of time that the application is paused for at any given time.

There are other even more complicated versions of the GC algorithms, but those should be enough to understand the basic approach.

As hinted at in the other answer, whether or not GC will ever run in the case of the sample application depends on how many times you go round the loop (what `Util.TOTAL_EXPECTED` evaluates to) and how big each `Message` object is compared to the size of the Java heap.